# Android: NonConfigurationInstances cannot be cast

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to retain a Radio (class I've made) array on onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance method, but then when I try to get it back with a cast to getLastNonConfigurationInstance, I'm having this error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$NonConfigurationInstances cannot be cast to me.android....lib.Radio[]

Here is my code:

```
    public void loadFeed() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    final Object data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

    // the activity is starting for the first time
    // read the json response and populate the radio stream list
    if(data == null) {

        //test
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        populateListFromJson();
    } else {

        //test
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // The activity was destroyed/created automatically, populate the radio stream
        // list with the info load by the previous activity
        final Radio[] radios = (Radio[]) data;
        for(Radio radio : radios) {
            radiosList.add(radio);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

@Override
public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return radios;
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: call getCustomNonConfigurationInstance instead

Comment: @GregGiacovelli, [getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance())